# which jsf-impl should i use?

Tags: jsf, tomcat, maven, jsf-2, primefaces

Where can i find a jsf-impl for my jsf 2 webapp ?

In maven's repo i got the 1.2 version.

In the http://download.java.net/maven/2/javax/faces/, i can see only the jsf-api, but no jsf-impl

Im currently using tomcat 7, and experimenting with primefaces.

Thank you !

---

### UPDATE

I've been able to get both the api and the impl using this, but im still not sure which impl i should really use :

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.sun.faces</groupId>
        <artifactId>jsf-api</artifactId>
        <version>2.0.3</version>
        <scope>compile</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.sun.faces</groupId>
        <artifactId>jsf-impl</artifactId>
        <version>2.0.3</version>
        <scope>compile</scope>
    </dependency>
```

---

### UPDATE

Sorry for not being clear, but it's not only about which version i should use.

I was doubtful because :

1. I notice the existence of 2 groupIds of javax.faces and com.sun.faces
2. I dont see the jsf-impl from the maven repository
3. What repository i should use to get the newest version

Thank you :-) !

Comment: We use the following in our project `<dependency>
            <groupId>com.sun.faces</groupId>
            <artifactId>jsf-impl</artifactId>
            <version>2.1.0-b09</version>
        </dependency>`  And it works smoothly

Comment: Thank you, i will switch to your suggestion now. But then, im still confused since there are javax.faces maven groupId also. I still wonder about when to use them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My suggestion is to use jsf-api and jsf-impl version 2.0.4. Because it has lot of bugfixes and improvements over 2.0.3.

You can download them from [this page](http://javaserverfaces.java.net/download.html) at this [link](http://java.net/projects/javaserverfaces/downloads/download/release%252Fmojarra-2.0.4-FCS-binary.zip). And have a look at the [MigrationGuide](http://javaserverfaces.java.net/nonav/rlnotes/2.0.4/migration.html) also.

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion on using 2.0.4. In my case, it's even more stable from the newer version, where my @FacesConverter doesnt work.

Comment: What is the difference between jsf-api and jsf-impl? What are they for? Can you please explain? @Selvin

Comment: @KorayTugay 
The API:
    the public types to which consumers can write code to

The implementation:

    private types consumers should not rely on
    implementation details including things like markup (e.g. HTML) and container (e.g. servlet)

http://stackoverflow.com/a/13049315/569497

Comment: @Selvin Can I use the api from myfaces and implementation from Mojorra? Also, where can I find a concrete example on this? Thanks for your answer by the way.